# What is the fastest way to determine if a table spans two pages?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The initial problem that led me to learn VBA is as follows:

You have a table that can be up to 10,000 rows (several hundred pages) long in a Word document. The table has a title in the form of a paragraph above the first row. This title is styled such that it links to a Table of Contents (`Style = "Caption"`). The table must be broken at the last row on each page, and the title must be inserted before the new table but in a different style that is not linked to the Table of Contents(`Style = "Caption Cont"`).

The first page will look like this:[image: linked to the ToC]

The second page will look like this: [image: not linked to ToC]

My first solution was relatively hackey and not at all elegant. I've managed to put together the following solution that works quite well. However, the initial process of determining the row number at which the table crosses pages is pretty slow due to the use of `Range.Information`. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to determine the bottom row on the page.

Putting the document into `wdNormalView` shaves off about a second per page, even with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`...

The program requires that your cursor is somewhere inside the table, which is fine and not a functionality I wish to remove.

It currently does about 120 pages per minute, with the majority of the time being spent on determining the row to split at (i.e. `splitNum`). I'm sure it can be much faster with a different method of determining `splitNum`.

**I CANNOT ADD AN ADDITIONAL ROW TO THE TABLE FOR THE PURPOSES OF USING "REPEAT HEADER ROWS".** 
It would violate regulations that are enforced in my industry, and a non-conforming document can be a huge hit to the company and future business

Code:

```vb
Sub tblSplit()

Dim timeCheck As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ActiveWindow.View = wdNormalView

timeCheck = Time

On Error GoTo ErrH

Dim crossRef As Range, delRange As Range, tblR As Range, newTbl As Range
Dim tblNumField As Range, tblNum As String

Set tblNumField = Selection.Tables(1).Range
tblNumField.MoveStart wdParagraph, -1
tblNum = tblNumField.Words(2)


Set crossRef = Selection.Tables(1).Range
Set thisTbl = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Range
Set tblR = Selection.Tables(1).Range
```

Insert cross-reference to title with style "Caption Cont"

```vb
crossRef.Move wdCharacter, -2
crossRef.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Table", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdOnlyCaptionText, ReferenceItem:=tblNum, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
crossRef.Text = vbCr & " (Cont.)" & vbTab


crossRef.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
crossRef.Style = "Caption Cont."
crossRef.Collapse wdCollapseStart

crossRef.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Table", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, ReferenceItem:=tblNum, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
crossRef.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
```

Delete duplicate title

```vb
Set delRange = crossRef.Duplicate

crossRef.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
crossRef.Copy
delRange.Text = vbNullString
```

**Find row at which table spans two pages**

```vb
Dim splitNum As Long, n As Long, i As Long, pageNum As Long
pageNum = tblR.Rows(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
i = 15
    Do
       If tblR.Rows(i).Next.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) <> pageNum Then
            splitNum = i
            Exit Do

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = 100 'arbitrary cap to prevent infinite loop

n = 1
```

Split and format

```vb
Do
    DoEvents


    'Split and format
    tblR.Tables(n).Split (splitNum)
    tblR.Tables(n).Rows.Last.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

    'Paste the stuff
    Set newTbl = tblR.Tables(n + 1).Range
    newTbl.Move wdParagraph, -2
    newTbl.Paste
    newTbl.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
    'Clear excess
    newTbl.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = vbNullString

    'Next
    n = n + 1
Loop Until tblR.Tables(n).Rows.Count < splitNum
```

Restore state, report time, safe-exit and error handler set-up for debugging

```vb
Application.ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Pages completed: " & n & vbCr & _
    "Time (sec): " & DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time) & vbCr & _
    "Seconds per page: " & CDbl(DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time)) / CDbl(n) & vbCr & _
    "Pages per minute: " & n / DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time) * 60


Exit Sub

ErrH:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Err.Raise Err.Number
    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: What about [repeating the table header](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-table-header-on-subsequent-pages-2ff677e0-3150-464a-a283-fa52794b4b41) row(s)?

Comment: @PeterT the actual title of the table is not in the header row, it is a separate paragraph. I cannot share a screenshot due to the nature of the document, but think of it as a paragraph of text before the table that is not technically associated with the table as far as VBA is concerned.

Comment: since this code is working and you just really want more speed, maybe you can also post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Maybe somebody there can take a crack at improving the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that makes it seem as if the paragraph is separate from the table, but it's really the first row. I created a table of data with a couple hundred rows, then inserted a new row on the top of the table. The paragraph goes into this empty row at the top. Assuming the rest of the table has borders enabled, disable the top, left, and right borders for the first row only. Then enable "repeat header row". It looks like this when you're done:

[image]

and then the second page:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the document gets converted to PDF and has to meet stringent requirements set forth by governmental regulatory bodies. I unfortunately can't use any formatting "tricks" that change the innate structure of the document. They are required to be separately titled and titled in specific formats. Plus, there is **actually** a header row as well as the title. Both need to be repeated. Let me see if I can create a mock-up and edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem you will have with any table-splitting approach is that it doesn't take account of the fact that Word uses the active printer driver to optimise the page layout.

Consequently, you may end up with what appears as the last row on a page when one printer is used ending up at the top of the next page when another printer is used. Alternatively, your headings might end up at the bottom of the page when a another printer is used.

As for your 'Caption'/'Caption Cont' Style machinations, that is all quite unnecessary if you create a full-with row for the caption at the top of the table and mark both the first and second rows as table header rows. Only the entry at the top of the table will appear in the Table of Contents. No code required.

Comment: The document is configured such that the margins are standard across the machines. Moreover, everyone uses the same printer and therefore has the same driver.

As stated in a response to nearly everyone who offered this as an option, creating a faux-header for the purposes of repeating header rows is not an option. I cannot do that because it would violate regulations that are enforced in my industry, and a non-conforming document can be a huge hit to the company and future business.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in a much simpler way by inserting the copy of the table caption in a row at the top of the second part of a split table.

1. Split the table at the end of the first page as you already do.  The rest of the activities now focus on the second part of the table.
2. For the second part of the table insert a single row at the top of the table.
3. Make the new single row a repeating table heading.
4. Paste the copy of the table caption in the row at the top of the second part of the table.

This will achieve the effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This doesn't achieve the uniformity that splitting the table does, nor does it allow for the actual header row associated with the table to be repeated across pages. I realize I probably wasn't explaining it well, so I edited my post to include some mockup screenshots that may be helpful.

Comment: Those objections are quite trivial and easily resolved with a little bit of additional coding.

Comment: how is this comment helpful?

Comment: It tells you that you are very close to a solution to your problem but not getting there because you give up at the first hurdle.  The small amount of additional code is to copy your repeating headers to the second part of the table before adding the single row to contain the copy of the caption.  Some code to turn off the top and left/right borders of the single cell, and then a small amount of code to make sure the second part table alignment matches that which you show in your updated question.

Comment: I'm aware of the ability to manipulate margins, as well as how to do a copy and paste, thanks. Neither your solution nor your additional input to "trivially" resolve the objections meet my goal, which is to split the table and insert the title in paragraph form. The task needs to be completed within organizational and regulatory parameters. If those requirements weren't in place, I would not even bother with splitting the table, and just repeat header rows. Maybe instead of saying that I give up at the first hurdle, you should look more carefully at the actual obstacle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206311/discussion-between-jclasley-and-freeflow).

Comment: No thanks.  As far as I'm concerned the horse has been led to the water.  I have nothing more I wish to add.